# 2g is not working in sed to skip the first occurrence of a match

Tags: linux, shell, unix, sed, sh

I am trying to replace some text in a xml file using sed. I am able to replace my text, but i want to skip the first occurence. i am using 2g, but it is not working. No error is displayed, but no change happens to file.

My Xml file :

```
<file-min-size>10830</file-min-size>
      <rotate-log>true</rotate-log>
<file-min-size>25600</file-min-size>
      <rotate-log>true</rotate-log>
<file-min-size>32300</file-min-size>
      <rotate-log>true</rotate-log>
<file-min-size>13456</file-min-size>
      <rotate-log>true</rotate-log>
```

My expected output :

```
<file-min-size>10830</file-min-size>
      <rotate-log>true</rotate-log>
<file-min-size>25600</file-min-size>
      <rotate-log>true insertvalue</rotate-log>
<file-min-size>32300</file-min-size>
      <rotate-log>true insertvalue</rotate-log>
<file-min-size>13456</file-min-size>
      <rotate-log>true insertvalue</rotate-log>
```

I am using the below sed command.

```
sed -i 's#</rotate-log>#insertvalue</rotate-log>#2g' myfile.xml
```

The above command is not working. if i remove 2g, then the text is repalcing. i want to skip the first occurence. Any help ?

Also when i run the command second time, the values are entering again. Is there a way to check and replace only if not available ?

Comment: Maybe start with the third line? `sed -i '3,$ s#</rotate-log># insertvalue</rotate-log>#g' file`

Comment: The file I have given above is a part of file where my parameters begins. Also, this parameters will be at different lines at different files. Any other way ?

Comment: But your pattern can only appear once on a line, right? Try `sed -i '/<\/rotate-log>/{:A;n;s#</rotate-log># insertvalue</rotate-log>#;bA}' file`. Check the [online demo](https://ideone.com/222dxO).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With GNU sed, you may use

```
sed -i '/<\/rotate-log>/{:A;n;s#</rotate-log># insertvalue</rotate-log>#;bA}' file
```

See the [online sed demo](https://ideone.com/222dxO)

The command finds the line with `</rotate-log>` and then

- `:A` - sets a label `A`
- `n` - discards the current pattern space value and reads the next line into it
- `s#</rotate-log># insertvalue</rotate-log>#` - replaces `</rotate-log>` with `# insertvalue</rotate-log>`
- `bA` - goes to `A` label (reads the next line, replaces, goes on).

Comment: This worked perfectly. Thanks a lot. Can you help me out with my second issue which is i need to replace only if the value is not present. I need to replace only if the value is not present. @wiktor-stribiżew

Comment: @Rajesh I think you may just use `sed -i '/<\/rotate-log>/{:A;n;s#\( insertvalue\)\{0,1\}</rotate-log># insertvalue</rotate-log>#;bA}' file`

Comment: Thanks a lot, it made my work easy. Thanks a lot again. One last thing, is there a way to mention the occurences to be skipped ? like we use 2g,3g,4g in normal sed commands.

Comment: @Rajesh No, you can't. You need some more advanced programming logic for that.

Comment: No problem. This has done my work. Thanks a lot for your time.

Comment: N.B. `n` sends the current pattern space to stdout (unless the `-n` option is set) then reads the next line in less its newline.